# How to handle Facebook login in MVVM design pattern

Tags: android, mvvm

As per Android recommendation in MVVM design pattern, ViewModal must not accept the reference of the View but In Facebook login we get the response in the method onActivityResult() of an Activity.

So if our ViewModal has a method for Facebook login then i have to pass the reference of the Activity to it, so that i get back the result in the method onActivityResult() of an Activity.

Would any body suggest how to handle Facebook login respecting the MVVM design pattern

Comment: I checked one app developed in my team and it does exactly what you said, it passes activity to ViewModel. I have my doubt that this is a good idea, but it works.

Comment: Hi UrosKekovic, Definitely it will work but it is not the recommended way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> ViewModels should not **hold** a reference to Activities, Fragments, or Contexts.

That means you can pass your activity or context in argument but you should not store that reference.

in your activity Call that function.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

     yourVm.onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?,this)
}
```

in your ViewModel make a function

```
 fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?,activity? : Activity) {

//do your work
}
```